# Terraform plan does not include all of my .tf changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am using AWS provider. I've added transaction blocks in my `lifecycle_rule` block with the appropriate `days` and `storage_class` properties. Besides that change I've also increased the `expiry_days` from 30 to 180.

The variable looks like this:

```
variable "bucket_details" {
  type = map(object({
    bucket_name = string
    purpose =     string
    infrequent_transition_days = number
    infrequent_transition_storage = string
    archive_transition_days = number
    archive_transition_storage = string
    expiry_days = number
    versioning =  bool
  }))
}
```

The resource looks like this: (I've removed unrelated configs)

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket-s3" {
  for_each = var.bucket_details

  bucket = "${each.key}-${var.region}-${var.environment}"

  lifecycle_rule {
    id =      "clear"
    enabled = true

    transition {
      days = each.value.infrequent_transition_days
      storage_class = each.value.infrequent_transition_storage
    }

    transition {
      days = each.value.archive_transition_days
      storage_class = each.value.archive_transition_storage
    }
  
    expiration {
      days = each.value.expiry_days
    }
  }
}
```

I've followed [this transition example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket) for reference.

When I run `transaction plan` I get the following output:

```
~ lifecycle_rule {
    abort_incomplete_multipart_upload_days = 0
    enabled                                = true
    id                                     = "clear"
    tags                                   = {}

  + expiration {
      + days = 180
    }
  - expiration {
      - days                         = 30 -> null
      - expired_object_delete_marker = false -> null
    }
}
```

No transition changes listed. Could it be because transition is AWS-specific and thus Terraform does not catch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code as is and here is the response:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

variable "region" {
  default = "us-west-2"
}

variable "environment" {
  default = "dev"
}

variable "bucket_details" {
  type = map(object({
    bucket_name = string
    infrequent_transition_days = number
    infrequent_transition_storage = string
    archive_transition_days = number
    archive_transition_storage = string
    expiry_days = number
  }))
  default = {
    hello_world = {
    bucket_name: "demo-001",
    infrequent_transition_days: 10,
    infrequent_transition_storage: "STANDARD_IA",
    archive_transition_days: 10,
    archive_transition_storage: "GLACIER",
    expiry_days = 30
  }}
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket-s3" {
  for_each = var.bucket_details

  bucket = "${each.key}-${var.region}-${var.environment}"

  lifecycle_rule {
    id =      "clear"
    enabled = true

    transition {
      days = each.value.infrequent_transition_days
      storage_class = each.value.infrequent_transition_storage
    }

    transition {
      days = each.value.archive_transition_days
      storage_class = each.value.archive_transition_storage
    }

    expiration {
      days = each.value.expiry_days
    }
  }
}
```

Response of Terraform plan:

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_s3_bucket.bucket-s3["hello_world"] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket-s3" {
      + acceleration_status         = (known after apply)
      + acl                         = "private"
      + arn                         = (known after apply)
      + bucket                      = "hello_world-us-west-2-dev"
      + bucket_domain_name          = (known after apply)
      + bucket_regional_domain_name = (known after apply)
      + force_destroy               = false
      + hosted_zone_id              = (known after apply)
      + id                          = (known after apply)
      + region                      = (known after apply)
      + request_payer               = (known after apply)
      + tags_all                    = (known after apply)
      + website_domain              = (known after apply)
      + website_endpoint            = (known after apply)

      + lifecycle_rule {
          + enabled = true
          + id      = "clear"

          + expiration {
              + days = 30
            }

          + transition {
              + days          = 10
              + storage_class = "GLACIER"
            }
          + transition {
              + days          = 10
              + storage_class = "STANDARD_IA"
            }
        }

      + versioning {
          + enabled    = (known after apply)
          + mfa_delete = (known after apply)
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Note: You didn't use the -out option to save this plan, so Terraform can't guarantee to take exactly these actions if you run "terraform apply"
now.
```

As you can see there are `transition changes`. Can you try setting defaults vars and check the response.

Comment: Thanks tomarv2, that's ruled out. I'll keep digging into it. The problem is that it's a big project which I am not yet familiar with and I am also beginner in Terraform.

Comment: This answer is correct for the purposes of StackOverflow. My specific issue wasn't lying in Terraform itself, but how our infrastructure was configured.